# User interface data

Tags: data-request, computing

Does anyone know how I can get my hand on a dataset of user interface interactions?
I am looking for things like clicked buttons, mouse movements or executed commands.

Many applications record these things to improve usability, but I can't seem to find any open datasets.

Another possibility would be data on the user interactions of a website (like which user clicked which link or completed which form).

Comment: I don't know if data from different websites have any sense. For instance, I cannot see a way to use this kind of data from facebook and from amazon together. So, I would ask if you are interesting to only one website.

Comment: We track all this stuff in our windows apps for analysis purposes and I guess I could make some available. This would be user interaction with store checkout systems. We use a binary format, but would you be happy with a csv dump of raw interaction? This would contain a basic log of all clicks, keystrokes, time etc.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris: Of course I don't want data from different sources mashed together. I just wanted to say that the specific source is not that important.

Comment: @rlb: I would greatly appreciate if you could generate a csv for me. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find key log data for keyboard usage?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/where-to-find-key-log-data-for-keyboard-usage)

Comment: @philshem: I see the overlap with this question, but tracking of mouse clicks is something different, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make some available from Retail systems, where the logs are the checkout operator. These are logs of main messages sent via PreTranslateMessage to the application. The operator tends to use the same screen all day, but there are a number of popup and child windows that show.  Our logs only show the inputs such as keystrokes and clicks; they do not show any output such as error messages. http://www.fieldpine.com/docs/tech/datasets.htm

I am not sure if these will contain enough information, depending on what your aim is. To fully understand and analyse you might also need to know some details about what button is positioned where. Maybe we can provide that too if needed but this is then getting quite specific. We have instrumentation all through the code and can track from user action, to processing flow, to final outcome. From your sale receipt we can track back to exact keystrokes if we want too.

At the moment I have only loaded a small sample so you can verify it has what you need, I will get some larger samples online next week.

Comment: Great, thank you, this is indeed very useful. I am trying to do some research in anomaly detection, so the outcome of a transaction would also be useful, but it is not required.

Comment: One of our primary aims with this tracking was exactly that purpose, realtime user problem detection and potential fraud, so I will ensure there is sufficient detail in the files to do that.