# Where to find key log data for keyboard usage?

Tags: data-request, computing

I am wondering if theres a dataset of key logs for keyboards of computers or even smartphones. It only needs to have the time and the key character for each key pressed.

Such as:

```
9:00 4/2/2014, a
9:01 4/2/2014, !
```

I know it could be very sensitive but could there be any public dataset for this?

Comment: You can always create your dataset. There are a few software that can record your keyboard and export a log like the one you need.

Comment: I doubt anyone would give you their logs (as it'd also have every one of their passwords in it) ... but there's plenty of "keylogger" software out there.

Comment: @Joe yes it has huge privacy issues. but I am just wondering if there's a chance some people have cleaned and published a dataset of key logs with a certain scale before.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Yes, but if the dataset has a certain scale and generality, then it would be better.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/7077/1511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few academic papers that have used keylogger data set. An example from 
*"A Case-Study of Keyloggers and Dropzones"* ([PDF link](http://www.ei.rub.de/media/emma/veroeffentlichungen/2012/08/06/dropzones-ESORICS09.pdf)):

> We found more than 33 GB of keylogger data, containing stolen information from more than 173,000 victims.

For security reasons, the authors gave the data to AusCERT (Australia’s National Computer Emergency Response Team), and it's mostly impossible that this data set is ever released. But the paper is very interesting in its explanation of how they collected the keylogger data.

---

Another paper, *"A Metric for the Evaluation and Comparison of Keylogger Performance"* ([PDF link](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/cset14/cset14-paper-fiebig.pdf)):

> (The authors have) developed a framework to assess the performance of a keylogger. This paper provides the documentation on how such a study can be conducted, while the required source code is shared online.

The analysis code (python) and keylogger data ([sql database format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666279/2327328)) is available as a download from the [Security in Telecommunications](http://www.isti.tu-berlin.de/security_in_telecommunications/) group at TU Berlin. The data is from tablets and smartphones.

> The toolkit also holds the test-data from the performed use-case study and a demo keylogger.

The git page is [here](https://gitlab.sec.t-labs.tu-berlin.de/mobile-keylogger/metric), and the direct download link is [here](https://gitlab.sec.t-labs.tu-berlin.de/mobile-keylogger/metric/repository/archive). The data files are called *KeyStrokesExperiment.sql* and *KeyStrokesRealExperiment.sql* in the "data" folder.

Comment: both papers are quite interesting and helpful. Thanks! I appreciate the thorough info.