# Keyboard keystrokes with timing

Tags: data-request, language, computing

Similar to this question: [Where to find key log data for keyboard usage?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/where-to-find-key-log-data-for-keyboard-usage)

...but it doesn't have the answers I am looking for.

I am researching keyboard layouts. I want to get timing data for each key to research delays in typing. I am trying to find what may contribute most to delays from key positions to language itself. If you know of any keystroke data sets that contain timings as well, that would be helpful.

It doesn't have to be too exhaustive or big. This is a hobby, not any kind of funded research.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this Medium post: **[Coursera and keystroke biometrics](https://medium.com/@pdehaye/coursera-and-keystroke-biometrics-550762f2f61b#.nnmazrccz)**, the author has published a sample of keystrokes with timing. The data is a little cryptic, but if you read the article it starts to be more clear.

- [Github Repo](https://github.com/pdehaye/Coursera_Safe_Harbor_requests)
- [CSV file](https://github.com/pdehaye/Coursera_Safe_Harbor_requests/blob/master/typing_sample.csv)

Although the data is limited, it may be possible to collect your own data on a larger scale using this method.

[image]

Comment: It's a start. The data is really limited. Not even all the letters of the alphabet are present... sadly. I was hoping some typing tester site (or something similar) had this info from a broad range of people doing all letters of the alphabet. I may have to write my own.

Answer (score 1):

I am the person who obtained that data originally. Take it with a grain of salt, as I was very much playing with the tool at the same time. I tried typing one finger at a time, swapping my hands, with the "Keyboard Privacy" Chrome extension enabled, etc. Let me know though if you can find cool visualisations or information within the data! I think it would be hard, but you might also have ideas on what the rest of the data represents.